# What is the best way to store single non-repeating data to a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, database, nosql

What is best practice for storing data in a database which ever only requires a single entry. An example would be configuration data which relates to the entire application/website. Is it common to create a table for this which has only a single entry?

I'm asking under the context of a MongoDB database though I think the question is also valid for SQL databases.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better to be handled by the application layer? It could be just a single text file where you can read/write key value pairs. Is there a particular reason to use databases?

Answer (score 6):

An example of an auxiliary table commonly found in databases would be called `Constants` and may hold such values of pi, the idea begin that all applications using the database are required to use the same scale and precision. In standard SQL, to ensure they is at most one row e.g. ([from Joe Celko](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic411110-403-1.aspx)):

```
CREATE TABLE Constants
(
 lock CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'X' NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 CHECK (lock = 'X'),
 pi FLOAT DEFAULT 3.142592653 NOT NULL,
 e FLOAT DEFAULT 2.71828182 NOT NULL,
 phi FLOAT DEFAULT 1.6180339887 NOT NULL, 
 ...
);
```

Because mySQL doesn't support `CHECK` constraint then a trigger is required to achieve the same.

Answer (score 5):

A table would be fine, no reason why not to use it just because it will have only one row.

I just had the weirdest idea (I wouldn't implement it but for some reason I thought of that). You can create a hard-coded view like this:

```
create view myConfigView 
as
select 'myConfigvalue1' as configValue1, 'myConfigvalue2' as configValue2
```

and do `select * from myConfigView`  :)

but again, no reason why not to use a table just because it will have only one row

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SQL DB, you will probably have columns like key name, and value and each attribute will be stored as a row.
In MongoDB, you can store all related configuration as a single JSON document

Comment: All right I suppose if all of your values are the same type, or you don't mind type conversions...

Answer (score 1):

I use a config table with a name (config_name) and a value (config_value). I even add a help field so that users can see what the name/value pair is intended for, or where it is used.

```
CREATE TABLE  config (
  config_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  config_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  config_value text NOT NULL,
  config_help text COMMENT 'help',
  PRIMARY KEY  (config_id),
  UNIQUE KEY ix_config_name (config_name),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then following php code recovers the value for a key, or returns an empty string. Assumes $db is an open database connection. All entries are forced to lower case.

```
function getConfigValue($name) {
    $retval='';
    $db = $this->db;
    $sql = 'select config_value from config where LOWER(config_name)="'.strtolower($name).'"';
    $result = $db->Query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        $row = $db->FetchAssoc($result);
        $retval = $row['config_value'];
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

All mysql/php in this instance, but the general principle remains.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB databases, I usually just make a new "table", but, for SQL databases, that entails a lot more (especially when others are also working on the same database; SQL isn't as malleable), so, you might want to be a bit more careful with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create table for configurations, as rainecc told, and use cache then to take that all table to memory :) and use it from there (cache). It will be the best.